# How does this EEG chip compare to modern EEG (is it still used now)?

Tags: amplifier, differential-amplifier, eeg

[image]

[image]

I got from my drawer last night a vintage Brainmaster 2E I bought late 1990s that I used only a few times during that period. It has serial port at back.

My question concerns the gain of the amplifier and the noise. It has this specification:

1. Notch Filtering: 40 Hz cutoff
2. Common Mode Rejection >100 dB
3. Gain 20,000
4. Sampling 8 Bit
5. Input Impedance 10 M ohms

It uses this pcb and chip:

[image]

[image]

What can you say about the chip? Is it so outdated already? What other applications use this chip?  Does DIY EEG also use this chip?  How does the chip compare to the average modern EEG and DIY EEG?

Comment: To quote the downvote button: _"This question does not show any research effort"_.

Comment: That's not an EEG chip I'm pretty sure--it looks like a 68000-based microcontroller.

Comment: The chip you're highlighting isntpart of the analog amplifier

Comment: The amplifier is the AD620's in the upper left

Comment: The chip is an old OTP (one-time programmable) 8-bit CMOS Microcontroller. Nothing specific to this application.

Answer (score 2):

Neurofeedback Devices are generally overpriced niche market products that vary in cost depending on the headset number of channels 5 to > 20 and the method of feedback for some unknown purpose.  It just converts some band of pulses into some unknown output display or sound.

The HC11 is a workhorse micro with limited capability compared to a Raspberry Pi but it how fancy you appreciate the feedback.

The prickly brainchild headset that doesn't need electrodes and gel costs > 25k$ https://brainmaster.com/product/freedom-20r-child-series/

I recall a 4 channel device DIY that fit into a baseball cap with electrodes and played MIDI-or Moog-like oscillator music from each frequency channel for Biofeedback for << $100 including PCB back in the 70's and no microcontroller.

Comment: The prickly brainchild headset is seemingly a lot for a multi-channel electrometer, but hey - it's all custom molded plastic parts and whatnot, at probably not that big of a volume. I don't think anyone could sell into this market for less, unless they lowered the price so much the market grew by an order of magnitude at least. If you wanted a home-made prototype, it could be hacked together with amazingly little investment. ENIG PCBs for electrodes, with an electrometer buffer and conformal coating on the wire side. Been there, done that myself, and it's no big deal mostly.

Answer (score 2):

The "chip" you show is the microcontroller with an integrated 8-bit A/D converter. It has nothing inherently to do with EEG. Nobody uses it today anymore, but that's not because it's inherently bad for what it does. There just are chips with much better development software support than HC11. People still could do viable retro-styled designs with those chips. Just because it's old it doesn't mean it's not useful. I'm sure it does today just what it did 30 years ago.

The analog chips - the instrumentation amplifier AD620 and the op amp OP90 and OP490 are still being made. They are not necessarily anyone's first choice anymore, but they work just fine within their specs.

The low-pass filtering is probably split between a 1st or 2nd order discrete filter and firmware boxcar averaging.

The overall design is serviceable for what it does, after all it's not as if 1996 was some dark ages. It seems to be competently done, but I haven't drawn the schematic for it. That's just judging by the components present. There's optical isolation for the serial connection.

You could replace the CPU with an Arduino UNO without loss of performance. And with a slightly better A/D converter - say 12 bit, 1kHz, you could get quite a bit better specs. We also have better high-impedance instrumentation amplifiers today.

The main problem you'd have using this device as-is would be figuring out the serial port protocol it uses. According to [Patent no. US5899867A](https://patents.google.com/patent/US5899867A/en), which covers this very device, the software at the time was most likely 16-bit, running on Windows 3.

Assuming that you could find the software somewhere, and a compatible PC or a virtual machine, you could connect the device and try and reverse engineer the protocol.

But, given how simple the system is, I doubt that would be worthwhile. Just interfacing the existing analog front-end to an Arduino would let you experiment. The front-end is not great by today's standards, but you'll get usable EEG data with it when your electrode application technique is good.

The state of the art in both EEG and EMG is active electrodes, where an ultra-low-leakage current amplifier is acting as an electrometer. Those raise the performance bar so far up that even in the early 1980s they made life much easier than what the poor sods in routine clinical use had to deal with. The active electrodes weren't popular because the op-amps they used weren't cheap, and people generally scoffed at sticking chips in what passed for a historically "low-cost" part of the system (the wiring harness).

Comment: Gain by itself is meaningless if you don't know what voltage range it maps to. Modern A/D converters can be quite sensitive, so you don't need much gain to get better resolution than older high-gain systems had. As for rechargeables - no idea. Probably NiCd cells based on the age of the system, and thus modern NiMH would work fine. You'd need to know how many cells it used. At least four would be needed to get the AD620 working just 0.2V above minimum working voltage of 4.6V. For 5 or more cells, the MCU would need a regulator or at least a dropper diode or B-E junction to lower the voltage.

Comment: If you still have the charger, then perhaps measuring the open circuit voltage will give you a hint about how many cells it charged.

Comment: @Jtl But I think the question you're asking is a bit lopsided: it's not about chips and stuff. It's about the signals you get out of that thing, and how they compare to what you need. It may be perfectly sufficient if you still got the software for it. You'd need to look at the actual data. Otherwise, a competent DIY solution would be quite a bit better in almost every way (usability, resolution, noise floor, artifact rejection, etc.)

Comment: @Jtl There are a couple transistors but I have not thought of what they are doing there. They are close to power input and battery connections so perhaps it’s a part of the charger. Hook it up to a power supply and see what voltage the charger puts out if you load it down with a 1k resistor in place of the battery.

Comment: see   https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/635144/is-pc-software-capable-of-bricking-the-hc11-via-com-port-and-how-to-recover-it?noredirect=1#comment1681596_635144   I was able to make it run using old pc and old software but bricked the HC11 with their new software. When you mentioned above I could use an Arduino UNO instead, did you mean I could still use their original Brainmaster software on the Arduino? or writing new Brainmaster software myself (which would be hard)? pls clarify bec if I can still use the original Brainmaster software then ill definitely get an Arduino UNO tnx