# Reprogramming the HC11 or using an Arduino Uno

Tags: microcontroller

Here is the s19 file with correct hex and checksum. The HC711E9 in the unit doesn't have enough ram (only 512 bytes and half used by buffalo) so I can't assemble/run it to ram and move it to the EEPROM (you know program can't be directly uploaded from buffalo to EEPROM. So please run it in your HC11 evaluation board (with more memory). Or disassemble the s19 file directly. Thanks.

[image]
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I found the adc to serial subroutine that can make it run again.. but only for channel 1, and I have to manually put the program at RAM and execute it everytime I turned it on. I can only make it load automatically by repairing the program at EEPROM. The following is the hex dump of the chip program. Can anyone help convert the machine language back to the HC11 assembly language so I can fix it?

[image]

I'm trying to reprogram the 68HC11 module which is very similar to the 68HC11 evaluation board. I can have full access to the microcontroller and all memory areas. I found the program to enable the A/C but I can't find the subroutine to send it to the serial port. Anyone knows how?

[image]

[image]

I found out I can access via Kermit the monitor program of the Brainmaster HC11 or BUFFALO. I thought only the Evaluation Boards can do this. Can you do this to all circuits with HC11? Or maybe the Brainmaster PCB is like that of the evaluation board. Anyway. Do you think it is easy to program from scratch the HC11 by simply getting inputs to the A/D converter and output them raw at serial ports? Who have experienced programming the HC11?

See https://www.youtube.com/shorts/ULyWcRLD7lU

Since the EEG module is just simply taking in analog inputs and sending them to the serial ports with the software doing all the processing, there could be common program subroutines for the HC11 out there, if I use it. Can it run?

Better yet, if I use an Arduino Uno, can I still use the original Brainmaster software and interface it to the Arduino or must one write the software from scratch?

Original message:

I have an original Brainmaster 2E unit. I was able to make it run with the original software.

However, after I downloaded the latest software from their website and ran it, it seemed to brick it (I guess they altered the EEPROM contents) in such a way that I couldn't use the original software on it anymore, even after a fresh Windows install.

It appeared they wanted to disable all old Brainmaster 2E units. No support anymore, they just told me to buy new unit costing $2000.

This is the HC11 microcontroller.

[image]

This is the Brainmaster 2E PCB to show you that the only chip that one can program is the HC11.

[image]

Comment: Possible? yes. Probably their GUI sent a kill command. If you have a BDM interface, you can flash a new firmware.

Comment: If they sent a kill command. are all functions disabled or does the conm port function still works bec the old software can still see the serial port and buffer, only no data coming out. how can i flash a new firmware when i dont have copy if it. you mean copy the firmware from old to new one?

Comment: If you could provide the program's dump as **text, not as image**, some of us could try to disassemble it. Anyway, perhaps your tool set includes a disassembler.

Comment: Done, I post it as text already. Please disassemble it. I don't have any disassembler. Thanks.

Comment: There are some "I" (letter) in your hex data, where there should be "1" (decimal). (I still have to find some free time for disassembling.)

Comment: One question per question please, this is all over the place. If you ask how to convert the s-record format to raw binary, then that's fairly straight-forward. If you hope to somehow salvage the program from there and move it to an Arduino... think again. Why would you migrate from one ancient 8-bitter to another ancient 8-bitter anyway? Pick a modern MCU if you are porting.

Comment: Btw.. let it be clear that I was not trying to port it to new MCU. It was just that their new software corrupted the module EEPROM. I bought the Brainmaster in 1999 for nearly $1000 as support at that time period version of Kickstarter. And I haven't used it ever since. I only tried to use it again last month. It worked in their old software. When I tried their new software, it instantly made the module inoperable. I tried to understand what happened. I looked inside the unit and found it has HC11 which I didn't even know was a microcontroller. Then I read up about it and learn how to read it.

Comment: To add. I just can't accept that after spending $1000 to support them 20 yrs ago and they are now earning millions of dollars, they want me to now spend another $2000 to buy new one. Support won't respond to my inquiry. And I don't want the $1000 unit to be a waste. In case anyone can find access to a Brainmaster 2E. Pls read EEPROM memory address B600-B7FF and share me the code/firmware so I can make my Brainmaster 2E run again (especially in 2 channels in which I couldn't figure out how to make it run). The steps how to copy it is in my Answer below.My email is albeplancvr@gmail.com Thanks

Answer (score 2):

As a partial answer, this is the result of an automated disassembly.

To decode the Motorola encoded bytes into a binary, I used the ubiquitous tool "objcopy" of GNU's binutils:

`objcopy -I srec -O binary routine.s1 routine.bin`

I'm afraid that there is something wrong with first ASCII strings, because they appear in the middle what seems to be code. Therefore, I did not let them be disassembled.

```
0000                ;
0000                ; M6811 Disassembler GDC Generated Source Code
0000                ;
0000                ;    Control File:  routine.ctl
0000                ;      Input File:  routine.bin
0000                ;     Output File:  routine.dis
0000                ;
0000                ; Memory Mappings:  ROM Memory Map: <Not Defined>
0000                ;                   RAM Memory Map: <Not Defined>
0000                ;                    IO Memory Map: <Not Defined>
0000                ;
0000                ;       Generated:  Sun Sep 25 15:03:04 2022
0000                ;
0000
0000
009D                L009D         =       0x009D                                      ; DRef: 0xB69B
00EB                L00EB         =       0x00EB                                      ; DRef: 0xB631
00EC                L00EC         =       0x00EC                                      ; DRef: 0xB636
00ED                L00ED         =       0x00ED                                      ; DRef: 0xB638
00FC                L00FC         =       0x00FC                                      ; DRef: 0xB628
0100                L0100         =       0x0100                                      ; DRef: 0xB66E,0xB6A7
0101                L0101         =       0x0101                                      ; DRef: 0xB679,0xB6AC,0xB6B1,0xB6BC
0102                L0102         =       0x0102                                      ; DRef: 0xB783,0xB791
0103                L0103         =       0x0103                                      ; DRef: 0xB658,0xB706
1000                L1000         =       0x1000                                      ; DRef: 0xB6ED,0xB766
1003                L1003         =       0x1003                                      ; DRef: 0xB722,0xB743
1004                L1004         =       0x1004                                      ; DRef: 0xB69D
102E                L102E         =       0x102E                                      ; DRef: 0xB776
102F                L102F         =       0x102F                                      ; DRef: 0xB77E
1030                L1030         =       0x1030                                      ; DRef: 0xB74A,0xB754
FF7C                LFF7C         =       0xFF7C                                      ; CRef: 0xB6CA
FF85                LFF85         =       0xFF85                                      ; CRef: 0xB696
FFAC                LFFAC         =       0xFFAC                                      ; CRef: 0xB680
FFC7                LFFC7         =       0xFFC7                                      ; CRef: 0xB6DF
FFCA                LFFCA         =       0xFFCA                                      ; CRef: 0xB6DB
0000
0000
B600                              .area   CODE1    (ABS)
B600                              .org    0xB600
B600
B600    CE 18 00 0F               .byte   0xCE,0x18,0x00,0x0F,0xF1,0x18
B600    F1 18
B606    C7          LB606:        .byte   0xC7                                        ; DRef: 0xB62A
B607    04          LB607:        .byte   0x04                                        ; DRef: 0xB74D,0xB757
B608                ; LB608: 0x24
B608    24          LB608:        .ascii  '$'                                         ; DRef: 0xB645,0xB76B
B609    03          LB609:        .byte   0x03                                        ; DRef: 0xB6E3
B60A    FF          LB60A:        .byte   0xFF                                        ; DRef: 0xB6F7
B60B    11          LB60B:        .byte   0x11                                        ; DRef: 0xB68D
B60C    16          LB60C:        .byte   0x16                                        ; DRef: 0xB688
B60D    04          LB60D:        .byte   0x04                                        ; DRef: 0xB683
B60E                ; 0x41,0x44,0x43,0x5F,0x50
B60E    41 44 43 5F               .ascii  'ADC_P'
B60E    50
B613    04                        .byte   0x04
B614                ; 0x41,0x44,0x43,0x5F,0x53
B614    41 44 43 5F               .ascii  'ADC_S'
B614    53
B619    04                        .byte   0x04
B61A                ; 0x41,0x44,0x43,0x5F,0x52
B61A    41 44 43 5F               .ascii  'ADC_R'
B61A    52
B61F    04                        .byte   0x04
B620
B620                ; ==================================================================
B620    1E 84 00 1C               brset   0x84,x,#0x00,LB640                          ; Branch Outside Loaded Source(s)
B624    24 40                     bcc     LB666
B626    A6 26                     ldaa    0x26,x
B628    94 FC                     anda    *L00FC
B62A    BA B6 06                  oraa    LB606
B62D    A7 26                     staa    0x26,x
B62F    86 7E                     ldaa    #0x7E
B631    97 EB                     staa    *L00EB
B633    CC B6 EB                  ldd     #0xB6EB
B636    97 EC                     staa    *L00EC
B638    D7 ED                     stab    *L00ED
B63A    CE 10 00                  ldx     #0x1000
B63D    86 00                     ldaa    #0x00
B63F    A7 02                     staa    0x02,x
B641    86 00                     ldaa    #0x00
B643    A7 07                     staa    0x07,x
B645    B6 B6 08                  ldaa    LB608
B648    84 18                     anda    #0x18
B64A    27 04                     beq     LB650
B64C    86 FF                     ldaa    #0xFF
B64E    20 08                     bra     LB658
B650                ; ------------------------------------------------------------------
B650    CE B7 B0    LB650:        ldx     #0xB7B0                                     ; CRef: 0xB64A
B653    BD B6 E3                  jsr     LB6E3
B656    A6 00                     ldaa    0x00,x
B658                ; ------------------------------------------------------------------
B658    B7 01 03    LB658:        staa    L0103                                       ; CRef: 0xB64E
B65B    18 CE B6 08               ldy     #0xB608
B65F    18 1F 00 40               brclr   0x00,y,#0x40,LB669
B65F    05
B664    CE B7 A1                  ldx     #0xB7A1
B667    8D 64                     bsr     LB6CD
B669                ; ------------------------------------------------------------------
B669    CE B6 1A    LB669:        ldx     #0xB61A                                     ; CRef: 0xB65F
B66C    8D 5F                     bsr     LB6CD
B66E    7F 01 00                  clr     L0100
B671    4F                        clra
B672    18 1F 00 20               brclr   0x00,y,#0x20,LB679
B672    02
B677    86 01                     ldaa    #0x01
B679                ; ------------------------------------------------------------------
B679    B7 01 01    LB679:        staa    L0101                                       ; CRef: 0xB672
B67C    0E                        cli
B67D                ; ------------------------------------------------------------------
B67D    CE B6 08    LB67D:        ldx     #0xB608                                     ; CRef: 0xB699,0xB6A0,0xB6AF,0xB6B9
B680    BD FF AC                  jsr     LFFAC                                       ; Branch Outside Loaded Source(s)
B683    B1 B6 0D                  cmpa    LB60D
B686    27 33                     beq     LB6BB
B688    B1 B6 0C                  cmpa    LB60C
B68B    27 24                     beq     LB6B1
B68D    B1 B6 0B                  cmpa    LB60B
B690    27 10                     beq     LB6A2
B692    81 0D                     cmpa    #0x0D
B694    27 05                     beq     LB69B
B696    BD FF 85                  jsr     LFF85                                       ; Branch Outside Loaded Source(s)
B699    20 E2                     bra     LB67D
B69B                ; ------------------------------------------------------------------
B69B    96 9D       LB69B:        ldaa    *L009D                                      ; CRef: 0xB694
B69D    B7 10 04                  staa    L1004
B6A0    20 DB                     bra     LB67D
B6A2                ; ------------------------------------------------------------------
B6A2    CE B6 1A    LB6A2:        ldx     #0xB61A                                     ; CRef: 0xB690
B6A5    8D 26                     bsr     LB6CD
B6A7    7F 01 00                  clr     L0100
B6AA    86 01                     ldaa    #0x01
B6AC    B7 01 01                  staa    L0101
B6AF    20 CC                     bra     LB67D
B6B1                ; ------------------------------------------------------------------
B6B1    7F 01 01    LB6B1:        clr     L0101                                       ; CRef: 0xB68B
B6B4    CE B6 0E                  ldx     #0xB60E
B6B7    8D 14                     bsr     LB6CD
B6B9    20 C2                     bra     LB67D
B6BB                ; ------------------------------------------------------------------
B6BB    0F          LB6BB:        sei                                                 ; CRef: 0xB686
B6BC    7F 01 01                  clr     L0101
B6BF    CE 10 00                  ldx     #0x1000
B6C2    1D 24 40                  bclr    0x24,x,#0x40
B6C5    CE B6 14                  ldx     #0xB614
B6C8    8D 03                     bsr     LB6CD
B6CA    7E FF 7C                  jmp     LFF7C                                       ; Branch Outside Loaded Source(s)
B6CD                ; ==================================================================
B6CD
B6CD
B6CD                ; ==================================================================
B6CD    18 CE B6 08 LB6CD:        ldy     #0xB608                                     ; CRef: 0xB667,0xB66C,0xB6A5,0xB6B7,0xB6C8
B6D1    18 1F 00 80               brclr   0x00,y,#0x80,LB6E2
B6D1    0C
B6D6    18 1E 00 02               brset   0x00,y,#0x02,LB6DF
B6D6    04
B6DB    BD FF CA                  jsr     LFFCA                                       ; Branch Outside Loaded Source(s)
B6DE    39                        rts
B6DF                ; ------------------------------------------------------------------
B6DF    BD FF C7    LB6DF:        jsr     LFFC7                                       ; Branch Outside Loaded Source(s)    CRef: 0xB6D6
B6E2    39          LB6E2:        rts                                                 ; CRef: 0xB6D1
B6E3                ; ==================================================================
B6E3
B6E3
B6E3                ; ==================================================================
B6E3    F6 B6 09    LB6E3:        ldab    LB609                                       ; CRef: 0xB653,0xB72A
B6E6    5A                        decb
B6E7    C4 07                     andb    #0x07
B6E9    3A                        abx
B6EA    39                        rts
B6EB                ; ==================================================================
B6EB
B6EB
B6EB                ; ==================================================================
B6EB    86 80                     ldaa    #0x80
B6ED    B7 10 00                  staa    L1000
B6F0    CE 01 01                  ldx     #0x0101
B6F3    1E 00 01 09               brset   0x00,x,#0x01,LB700
B6F7    F6 B6 0A                  ldab    LB60A
B6FA                ; ------------------------------------------------------------------
B6FA    48          LB6FA:        lsla                                                ; CRef: 0xB6FC
B6FB    5A                        decb
B6FC    26 FC                     bne     LB6FA
B6FE    20 60                     bra     LB760
B700                ; ------------------------------------------------------------------
B700    CE 01 00    LB700:        ldx     #0x0100                                     ; CRef: 0xB6F3
B703    A6 00                     ldaa    0x00,x
B705                ; ------------------------------------------------------------------
B705    4C          LB705:        inca                                                ; CRef: 0xB70B
B706    B4 01 03                  anda    L0103
B709    81 FF                     cmpa    #0xFF
B70B    27 F8                     beq     LB705
B70D    4D                        tsta
B70E    26 01                     bne     LB711
B710    4C                        inca
B711                ; ------------------------------------------------------------------
B711    A7 00       LB711:        staa    0x00,x                                      ; CRef: 0xB70E
B713    CE B6 08                  ldx     #0xB608
B716    1E 00 04 2E               brset   0x00,x,#0x04,LB748
B71A    1E 00 08 20               brset   0x00,x,#0x08,LB73E
B71E    1E 00 10 18               brset   0x00,x,#0x10,LB73A
B722    F6 10 03                  ldab    L1003
B725    36                        psha
B726    37                        pshb
B727    CE B7 30                  ldx     #0xB730
B72A    8D B7                     bsr     LB6E3
B72C    33                        pulb
B72D    32                        pula
B72E    6E 00                     jmp     0x00,x                                      ; Undetermined Branch Address
B730                ; ==================================================================
B730
B730    01 05 05 05               .byte   0x01,0x05,0x05,0x05,0x05,0x05,0x05,0x01
B730    05 05 05 01
B738                ; 0x20
B738    20                        .ascii  ' '
B739    0C                        .byte   0x0C
B73A
B73A                ; ==================================================================
B73A    8D 2E       LB73A:        bsr     LB76A                                       ; CRef: 0xB71E
B73C    20 05                     bra     LB743
B73E                ; ------------------------------------------------------------------
B73E    16          LB73E:        tab                                                 ; CRef: 0xB71A
B73F    C4 01                     andb    #0x01
B741    26 03                     bne     LB746
B743                ; ------------------------------------------------------------------
B743    B6 10 03    LB743:        ldaa    L1003                                       ; CRef: 0xB73C
B746                ; ------------------------------------------------------------------
B746    8D 22       LB746:        bsr     LB76A                                       ; CRef: 0xB741
B748                ; ------------------------------------------------------------------
B748    86 10       LB748:        ldaa    #0x10                                       ; CRef: 0xB716
B74A    B7 10 30                  staa    L1030
B74D    B6 B6 07                  ldaa    LB607
B750    8D 31                     bsr     LB783
B752    86 14                     ldaa    #0x14
B754    B7 10 30                  staa    L1030
B757    B6 B6 07                  ldaa    LB607
B75A    44                        lsra
B75B    44                        lsra
B75C    44                        lsra
B75D    44                        lsra
B75E    8D 23                     bsr     LB783
B760                ; ------------------------------------------------------------------
B760    CE 10 00    LB760:        ldx     #0x1000                                     ; CRef: 0xB6FE
B763    1D 25 3F                  bclr    0x25,x,#0x3F
B766    7F 10 00                  clr     L1000
B769    3B                        rti
B76A                ; ==================================================================
B76A
B76A
B76A                ; ==================================================================
B76A    37          LB76A:        pshb                                                ; CRef: 0xB73A,0xB746,0xB798
B76B    F6 B6 08                  ldab    LB608
B76E    C4 01                     andb    #0x01
B770    26 04                     bne     LB776
B772    4D                        tsta
B773    26 01                     bne     LB776
B775    4C                        inca
B776                ; ------------------------------------------------------------------
B776    F6 10 2E    LB776:        ldab    L102E                                       ; CRef: 0xB770,0xB773,0xB77B
B779    C5 80                     bitb    #0x80
B77B    27 F9                     beq     LB776
B77D    01                        nop
B77E    B7 10 2F                  staa    L102F
B781    33                        pulb
B782    39                        rts
B783                ; ==================================================================
B783
B783
B783                ; ==================================================================
B783    B7 01 02    LB783:        staa    L0102                                       ; CRef: 0xB750,0xB75E
B786    CE 10 30                  ldx     #0x1030
B789    C6 01                     ldab    #0x01
B78B                ; ------------------------------------------------------------------
B78B    1F 00 80 FC LB78B:        brclr   0x00,x,#0x80,LB78B                          ; CRef: 0xB78B
B78F    08                        inx
B790                ; ------------------------------------------------------------------
B790    17          LB790:        tba                                                 ; CRef: 0xB79E
B791    B4 01 02                  anda    L0102
B794    27 04                     beq     LB79A
B796    A6 00                     ldaa    0x00,x
B798    8D D0                     bsr     LB76A
B79A                ; ------------------------------------------------------------------
B79A    08          LB79A:        inx                                                 ; CRef: 0xB794
B79B    58                        lslb
B79C    C1 10                     cmpb    #0x10
B79E    2D F0                     blt     LB790
B7A0    39                        rts
B7A1                ; ==================================================================
B7A1
B7A1                ; 0x42,0x4D,0x5F,0x43,0x52,0x5F,0x57,0x52
B7A9                ; 0x53,0x57,0x26,0x54,0x46,0x43
B7A1    42 4D 5F 43               .ascii  'BM_CR_WRSW&TFC'
B7A1    52 5F 57 52
B7A1    53 57 26 54
B7A1    46 43
B7AF    04 03 03 07               .byte   0x04,0x03,0x03,0x07,0x0F,0x1F
B7AF    0F 1F
B7B5                ; 0x3F,0x70
B7B5    3F 70                     .ascii  '?p'
B7B7    0F FF FF FF               .byte   0x0F,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF
B7B7    FF FF FF FF
B7BF    FF                        .byte   0xFF
```

As you can see, I used the [m68dis](https://sourceforge.net/projects/m6811dis/) disassembler. Unfortunately its Linux version is too old for my system, so I ran the Windows version with [Wine](https://www.winehq.org/). The following is the used control file.

```
load B600 routine.bin binary

output disassembly routine.dis

addresses on
ascii on
dataopbytes on
opbytes on

tabs off

entry B620
entry B6EB
```

Comment: @Jtl Decode: see edit. -- Why not disassemble the first bytes? As I wrote, it seems overwritten and therefore makes no sense.

Comment: I remember that there used to be a [GCC compiled for DOS by DJGPP](http://www.delorie.com/djgpp/). IIRC it uses a memory extender, but the simpler tools should work. -- Another fine project is [srecord](http://srecord.sourceforge.net/), but you might need to compile it for your DOS, if that's possible at all.

Comment: My computer is an old Thinkpad T400 running Manjaro Linux, a nice and stable machine. However, I have a good background in CS, being "socialized" to computers as an autodidact in the 80s. -- I'm still thinking how to provide a binary file here on SE/EE, and I'm afraid that it is not possible. Obviously mot2bin writes the binary file filling all bytes beginning from address 0. Please try `load 0 your_routine.bin binary` replacing the first one in the control file.

Comment: @jtl Please read m6811dis' documentation. It is a kind of "smart" disassembler: Without any hint for entry points it cannot know what is executable code and what is data. Jump targets give next entry points, and so on. Dumb disassemblers sometimes generate erroneous listings because they try to interpret data bytes as opcodes. -- I started with `entry B600` but I saw quickly that this was not a good idea because the code looked wrong. Then I incrementally tried following addresses until I came to these two entry points. Actually it needed not more than 2 or 3 tries.

Comment: Please post a new question, SE/EE ist not a forum. ;-) It will help us to reproduce, if you provide a link to the simulator in this new question. You might link to it here to connect both questions.

Comment: is THRSim11 related to electronics? it's only a simulation. I'm afraid it may be off topic. Do you know a SE community where I can ask about THRSim11?

Comment: Perhaps at StackOverflow. It is a question that covers "_software tools commonly used by programmers_", isn't it?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot "reprogram" an HC711E9 at all. In the plastic package, they are OTP since there is no way to get short-wave UV to the die surface to erase the chip EPROM program memory.

If you can source factory new-old stock chips you can program those.

Comment: 68HC711E20 is still in production and fully compatible with E9. It ain't cheap however.